# Animated show with this "trial by cards" scene with a twist

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I am trying to find an animated show I watched as a kid, probably sometime around mid 2000s. It was either an anime or western animation. Sadly I can't remember much: it was probably in a fantasy setting with a group of characters on some sort of quest. **However, I can remember one very specific scene:**

There was a religious order of some sort led by an evil (older?) man. I think some (female) members of the order looked somewhat like Catholic nuns. The heroes were captured or needed something from the evil religious leader. At some point, one of the heroes had to undergo a sort of trial (like a divine trial) presided over by the religious leader. The leader had two cards, each with a distinct symbol - one had a "good" symbol, the other a "bad" symbol. The trial went like this: the leader shuffled those two cards and the hero had to pick one (obviously with the cards reversed so he couldn't see the symbols). If he picked the card with the "bad" symbol, he would fail the trial. Don't remember the exact consequences, maybe like imprisonment or execution.

However, the religious leader had this trick: once he shuffled the cards, he used some sort of magic to change the symbol on the "good" card to the "bad" symbol. So that both cards had the bad symbols and the trial could not possibly be passed. However, the hero knew about that, because a member of the religious order - one of the "nuns" - tipped him off.

So the hero passed the trial using this trick: after he picked a card, he deliberately "accidentally" dropped it into a fire (thus destroying it). And then he said to the religious leader something like: "Oops, sorry I dropped it, lets look on the other card to see which card I actually picked". And since the other card was "bad", the card that the hero picked (and burned) *had* to be the "good" one.

Also I think that the quest the group of heroes were on probably had to do with collecting some sort of magical stones/diamonds/artifacts? and they had a belt with slots for these, but I might be confusing it with some other show.

Sorry I can't remember more details, but if someone recognizes the scene above, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but please understand that this is not a matter of the question being bad, just that we want to tie identical questions together in the system, and the police for [[tag:story-identification]] is that if they name the same work, they're considered identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(TV_series))* just based on the belt with gems and you're looking for the "[Noradz the Clean](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Noradz_the_Clean)" episode with the [Cup](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Cup).

> The prisoners were made to undergo a trial, where the sacred Cup was to decide their fate. Lief was the one to pick the card, so was made to face the front while Reece put the cards in the Cup. This was when he noticed Tira, a girl he had saved from punishment, silently mouthing out words to him. She warned him that both the cards read 'Death', and Lief realised that the cards must have been switched. When Reece ordered him to turn around, he called upon the calming powers of the Topaz, to clear his mind. He drew a card out of the Cup, and instantly whirled around, seeming to trip, and dropped the card into the fire, burning it to ashes. Lief apologised for his clumsiness, but told Reece to look in the Cup, saying that the card he chose could be easily determined by looking at which card remained in the Cup. One of the other Ra-Kacharz drew the remaining card, which read 'Death', indicating that Lief had chosen the 'Life' card.

Comment: Damn that was fast. I think that is almost certainly it, I will accept once I check.

Comment: *Deltora Quest* comes up fairly often, and I found the episode with a search for `deltora quest burn card`

Comment: Thanks that was it. I clearly didn't remember that episode that accurately.